# save web page source javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to save the source website by javascript and send them via socket, but I have a problem. Written string is badly formatted. Everything is in one line, so that javascript does not work.
I tried:

```
var html = document.documentElement.outerHTML; //document.outerHTML

var html = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.documentElement);


var html = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document);
```

And I tried to encode to base64.
How to save a web page so that later work?

Comment: save where? on server side? on browser side? temporaly in a var?

Comment: maybe use phantomjs?

Comment: Temporaly in a var, to send by socket.io. When server receive a save in the database. I don't use phantomjs.